# Separation of concerns in Ojet ViewModel

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, oracle-jet

I'm creating a new OJET Application using the default nav template. My ViewModel code is becoming huge as I have many validations and APIs to call. How can I separate my entire validation logic in a separate JS file and import this file into my ViewModel. I tried to create a new file at the main.js level and added it to the define section of m viewmodel, but that's not working.

Answer (score 1):

OJET has the library require.js which enables lazy loading.

In your ViewModel code, you must define your dependencies, in a similar way as here, and pass it as a parameter to be able to call this import (be careful with the order of the dependencies in define):

```
define([..., 'your-dependency-here', ...],
  function(..., dependency, ...) {
    dependency.function();
```

You need also to pass this new file in path_mapping.json in your js folder, something like this:

```
"your-dependency-here": {
  "debug": {
      "path": "path/to/dependency/from/jsFolder"
  },
  "release": {
      "path": "path/to/dependency/from/jsFolder"
  }
}
```

Also, do not create a loop of your dependencies, which cause an error in require.js.